# Refactor react code to improve performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am new in coding in React and I have just joined a new organization where I need to send my code for review .The functionality is working fine but it seems to me that code in my component has become very lengthy ,also my submithandler method is making me iterate the array a couple of times,I don't know how to do it other way.Is there any way I can shorten my code to make it look better and increase the performance??Currently its taking a long time to show the data after i click submit ,looks like iteration oof array is taking time.

Also,If i close the browser after clicking the submit button, the ajax pending request is still in progress.I want to end the request and stop loading once i close the browser or navigate to other page.myRequestor is a third party library of my organization that can be used to send a request.Please help me shorten the code and fix the pending ajax request issue.Below is the code that I have tried to do.

```
const propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  tenant: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any),
  myRequestor: PropTypes.object, // eslint-disable-line react/forbid-prop-types
  };


let myRequestor = null;

const CallerUtil = () => {
myRequestor = React.useContext(MyRequestorContext);
return <ApplicationLoadingOverlay isOpen backgroundStyle="clear" />;
}


class ReadinessComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        body: '',
        tenant: null,
        error: null,
        errorMsg: '', 
        isOpen: false,
        showTable: false,
        isInvalid: false,
        isLoading: false,
        tenantId: '',
        items: [],
        tenantItems : null
    };

    this.onChangeTenantDropDown = this.onChangeTenantDropDown.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitHandler = this.onSubmitHandler.bind(this);
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
    this.tenantIdHandler = this.tenantIdHandler.bind(this);
    this.onClose = this.onClose.bind(this);
    this.addNewTenant = this.addNewTenant.bind(this);
    this.fetchInitial = this.fetchInitial.bind(this);
   }

componentDidMount() {
  this.mounted = true;
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  this.fetchInitial();

  }
componentWillUnmount(){
    
    this.mounted = false;

  }

onChangeTenantDropDown(value) {
    this.setState({
        tenant: value,
    });

  const info = this.state.tenantItems.find(function (t) { return t.name == value })
  this.setState({
    tenantId: info.id,
  });

}

  onSubmitHandler() {
    if (this.state.body == '') {
      this.setState({ isInvalid: true });
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    const params = {
      "tenantId": this.state.tenantId,
      "tenantShortName": this.state.tenant,
      "contactName": this.state.body
    }

    const { request } = myRequestor.get({
      url: '/getReadinessCheck',
      params: params,
    });

   // request.then(async ({ data }) => {
      request.then(({ data }) => {
      console.log(this.mounted);
      if (!this.mounted) {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        return;
      }
        
      console.log(data);
      
      let abc = data.find(vrsn => vrsn.name === 'TENANT_ERROR');         
      if (abc === undefined) {
        this.setState({ error: 'Failure', errorMsg:'Invalid Tenant',isLoading: false, isOpen: true, showTable: false, body: '', tenantId: ''});
        return;
      }
      let readinessResp = data.map(version => (version.latest === true ? { ...version, name: version.name.concat('_LATEST') } : version))
      readinessResp.sort(function (a, b) {
        var textA = a.name.toUpperCase();
        var textB = b.name.toUpperCase();
        return textA.localeCompare(textB);
      });

      this.setState({ items: readinessResp, error: 'Success', showTable: true, isLoading: false });
    }).catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error: 'Failure', errorMsg:'Failure', isLoading: false, isOpen: true, showTable: false ,body: '', tenantId: '' });
      });
    
  }


onChangeHandler(event) {
    this.setState({
        body: event.target.value,
    });
}

tenantIdHandler(event) {
  this.setState({
    tenantId: event.target.value,
  });
}

onClose() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        isOpen: !prevState.isOpen,
    }));
}


addNewTenant(shortName,tenantId){
  const newTenantShortName = shortName;
  const newTenantId = tenantId;
  const newTenant = {'name':newTenantShortName, 'id':newTenantId};
  this.setState({
    tenantItems: [...this.state.tenantItems, newTenant]
});     

}

fetchInitial() {
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  const { request } = myRequestor.get({
    url: '/tenants'
  });
   
  request
  .then(({ data }) => {
    if(data[0].hasOwnProperty("error")){
      this.setState({ error: 'Failure', errorMsg:data[0]['error'], isOpen: true, isLoading: 
   false,tenantItems: [{'name':'Default', 'id':'Default'}]});
      return;
    }

    let tenantsList = data;
    let tenants =[];
    tenantsList.map(tenant => ( tenants.push({'name':tenant.shortName, 'id':tenant.key})))

  this.setState({
    tenantItems: tenants,isLoading: false
  });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    this.setState({ error: 'Failure', isOpen: true, isLoading: false});
  });
  }


  render() {
      const {
   error, isOpen, body,showTable
       } = this.state;

if (this.state.tenantItems === null) {
  return <CallerUtil />;
  }

if(this.state.isLoading){
    return <ApplicationLoadingOverlay isOpen backgroundStyle="clear" />;
}

if (showTable) {
    return (<div>
    <h1>Readiness Status</h1>
    <ReadinessComponentView readinessInfo={this.state.items} /></div>);
}

return (
  <div className="ruleSupportEvaluation">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Column>
          <Heading level={1}>Readiness Check</Heading>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Column className="ruleSupportEvaluation" large={3} medium={3}>
          <div>
            <Heading className="info" level={3}>About</Heading>
            <Divider />
            <Text className="description" fontSize={18}>
              Readiness Check
            </Text>
          </div>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column className="ruleSupportEvaluation" large={8} medium={8}>
          <div>
            <div className="readinessComponent">
            <Tenant
              tenant={this.state.tenantItems}
              change={this.onChangeTenantDropDown}
            />
            <ModalManagerExample addNewTenant={this.addNewTenant} />
            </div>
            <InputField type="text" label="Tenant-Id" value={this.state.tenantId} placeholder="Tenant Id" onChange={this.tenantIdHandler}/>
            <InputElement isInvalid ={this.state.isInvalid} change={this.onChangeHandler} value={body} />                
            <Submit click={this.onSubmitHandler} />
            
            {error === 'Failure' &&
              (
                <Notification
                  errorMessage={this.state.errorMsg}
                  close={this.onClose}
                  isOpen={isOpen}
                />
              )
             }
          </div>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
  </div>
);
     }
 }

ReadinessComponent.propTypes = propTypes;

export default ReadinessComponent;
```

Comment: Questions regarding refactoring and optimizing working code are better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. With that said make sure to read their help guidelines for how to ask and what not to ask. As for your ajax problem please try to scale this down to only enough to display that issue without any of the code not relevant to the specific problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @charlietfl mentioned - codereview.stackoverflow.com is probably your best bet, however:

First quick win is take all of the `.bind(this)` stuff from your constructor and for those methods, define them in your class like this:

**BEFORE:**

```js
onChangeTenantDropDown(value) {
    this.setState({
        tenant: value,
    });

  const info = this.state.tenantItems.find(function (t) { return t.name == value })
  this.setState({
    tenantId: info.id,
  });

}
```

**AFTER:**

```js
onChangeTenantDropDown = (value) => {
    this.setState({
        tenant: value,
    });

  const info = this.state.tenantItems.find(function (t) { return t.name == value })
  this.setState({
    tenantId: info.id,
  });

}
```

> Note the arrow function.

You can also set state directly as a class property, so remove `this.` from where you define your state and move it outside of the constructor, i.e.:

```js
class ReadinessComponent extends Component {
  state = {
        body: '',
        tenant: null,
        error: null,
        errorMsg: '', 
        isOpen: false,
        showTable: false,
        isInvalid: false,
        isLoading: false,
        tenantId: '',
        items: [],
        tenantItems : null
    };
    ...
}
```

Now you can totally remove the constructor too :)

Hopefully that gets you at least part of the way there

> Totally recommend learning Hooks if you're new, it will really help clean up components like this - here's some links:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html
- https://blog.bitsrc.io/fetching-data-in-react-using-hooks-c6fdd71cb24a
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/06/introduction-swr-react-hooks-remote-data-fetching/

**EDIT**

In response to your comment:

```js
onSubmitHandler = async () => {
    const { body, tenantId, tenant: tenantShortName, body: contactName } = this.state;
    if (!body) {
        this.setState({ isInvalid: true });
        return;
    }

    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    const params = {
        tenantId,
        tenantShortName,
        contactName,
    };

    try {
        const { request } = myRequestor.get({
            url: '/getReadinessCheck',
            params,
        });
        
        const { data } = await request;

        if (!this.mounted) {
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
            return;
        }

        let abc = data.find((vrsn) => vrsn.name === 'TENANT_ERROR');
        if (abc === undefined) {
            this.setState({
                error: 'Failure',
                errorMsg: 'Invalid Tenant',
                isLoading: false,
                isOpen: true,
                showTable: false,
                body: '',
                tenantId: '',
            });
            return;
        }
        let readinessResp = data.map((version) =>
            version.latest === true ? { ...version, name: version.name.concat('_LATEST') } : version,
        );
        readinessResp.sort(function (a, b) {
            var textA = a.name.toUpperCase();
            var textB = b.name.toUpperCase();
            return textA.localeCompare(textB);
        });

        this.setState({ items: readinessResp, error: 'Success', showTable: true, isLoading: false });

    } catch (err) {
        this.setState({
                error: 'Failure',
                errorMsg: 'Failure',
                isLoading: false,
                isOpen: true,
                showTable: false,
                body: '',
                tenantId: '',
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.But I see my submitHandler method code is making me iterate the response a couple of times.Could you please help me on how can i shorten the submitHandler method code?